# ember containerview not update

Tags: ember.js, view

I have defined a container view, and I want to dynamically add child view to property 'childviews' ,then I have the code below:

```
export default Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  childViews:['testView'],
  testView:InfopanelView.create(),
  testView2:InfopanelView.create(),
  init:function(){
    this._super();
  },
  addSuccessMessage:function(){    
    this.pushObject(this.get('testView2'));
    console.log(this.get('childViews'));
  }
});
```

when the method addSuccessMessage was called the childViews will have 2 children,but the page seems not updated,so what is the problem

Comment: I am so sorry I did not operate the same object,and I found the solution

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that I did not operate the correct containeview object created by ember, cause I have the code below:

```
{{view "MyNameContainerView"}}
```

so this is the correct object I should save and operate,for that,I add code in the ContainerView.extend method:

```
export default Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  //other code
  didInsertElementpublic:function()
  {
    //save this in somewhere
    xxxxx.set('containerview',this);
  }
});
```

then we can add childview anywhere:

```
//controller.js
var childview = ChildView.create();
//or xxxx.get('containerview').addSuccessMessage()
xxxx.get('containerview').pushObject(childview);
```